# How to ask the user to accept self signed certificates ? WebView

Tags: react-native, webview

I am using WebView in my react native app. ( I use expo too).
My problem is I can't access the url because the connection is not secured and  the user needs to be able to accept the certificates. The app shows a blank page without asking anything.

Here is my current code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { WebView  } from 'react-native';

export default class WebLoginScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
      source={{uri: 'http://crm.sigram.fr/soeman'}} 
    />

    );
  }
}
```

How can I ask the user to accept the certificates ? Is it possible with WebView ? I can use other components if needed.